# sshfs with two consecutive ssh authentications

Tags: ssh, sshfs

with two consecutive ssh authentications I mean the following:

- I ssh to remote system A
- from remote system A, I ssh to remote system B

There is no way to ssh to B directly.

I have no problems mounting directories from A using sshfs.

I thought about mounting directories from B on A but unfortunately A does not have sshfs installed. Even if, I would not know if it works.

Is there maybe another way to access directories on B in a convenient way?

---

My `~/.ssh/config` looks like this now:

```
Host A
User user
HostName A.example.com
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p

Host B
User user
HostName B.example.com
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p A
```

How would my `sshfs` command look like?

This does not work:

```
sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions -o user@B.example.com:/somedir ~/somedir
```

It outputs the error message:

> remote host has disconnected

Comment: What does it mean "does not work"? What errors you get? How does the debug log look like?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ProxyCommand` or `ProxyJump` to do that transparently for the end application (`sshfs`). For example in `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host A
  # other configuration options needed
Host B
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p A
```

Then you should be able to use `sshfs` transparently by directly specifying host `B`.

Comment: Update the config to the question. It is not readable here. Also clarify if you see some errors or whatever.